# Non-uniform lens flares

Tags: optics, refraction, astrophotography

I assume -- and maybe wrong -- that lens flares, in photography, are caused by light getting "trapped" inside the curved lens and bouncing around (due to refraction and non-perfect total internal reflection) causing bright spots at periodic intervals, when they partially escape on the imaging side. This would give the classic circular(ish) spots when a camera pans up towards, say, the sun, where the shape of the spots mimics that of the lens/lenses and aperture.

However, I was looking at the Hubble Deep Field image and noticed that a few of the brighter stars have *only* horizontal and vertical flares. Similarly, stars (as in the light source) are often drawn as *n*-pointed polygons, implying distinct flares at regular angles.

What is it about the lens, in these cases, that causes flares to propagate seemingly non-uniformly or directionally?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to correct flares and sharply focus on my telescope when viewing planets.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25637/)